# Skip module with Maven enforcer

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm using `enforcer` plugin in a multi-node project in the root pom, but I have one testing module, that I don't really care to run the plugin there since it won't create any jar and is only for testing purposes. Is there any way to skip one of the modules in the plugin config?.

Checking the documentation I cannot find anything. Only how to ban some specific dependencies. https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html

The solution to put the plugin in each sub-module is possible but it's dangerous, since if I create a new sub-module I might forget to add it there.

Here my plugin config.

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>enforce-maven-version-and-dependencies</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <rules>
                  <requireMavenVersion>
                    <version>3.3.9</version>
                  </requireMavenVersion>
                  <bannedDependencies>
                    <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
                  </bannedDependencies>
                  <dependencyConvergence></dependencyConvergence>
                </rules>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <fail>true</fail>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the POM of the module, set `enforcer.skip` to `true`:

```xml
<properties>
  <enforcer.skip>true</enforcer.skip>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 35):

Alternatively when building the specific module from command line you can use the following command option.

```
mvn -Denforcer.skip=true clean install
mvn -Denforcer.skip=true clean package
```

Comment: The `=true` is not necessary.

Comment: In PowerShell, use double quotes: `mvn clean package "-Denforcer.skip"`